# Spread Operator PHP

Tags: php

I'm making exercices for PHP and I need more information.

I have this prototype:

```php
string my_cat_files(string $path, ...);
```

I understand what the spread operator can do, and there is the same for php.

But that I don't know is why this spread is not associated with a variable ?

Thank you so much if you can explain me what these `...` do without give me the solution **please** !

Edit:
**What I need to do**
Write a function that returns the content of the files whose paths are passed as parameters. There will be a 5 character line "_" between the contents of each file.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a spread operator. Can you give more context about the function?

Comment: Yup wait a little

Comment: Edited now  ..

Comment: That's indeed to indicate that there can be any number of arguments. However, I think the one who wrote the signature example was too lazy to add a variable name, as it is in official documentations of such functions

Comment: That are terrible... But thank you il will foreach on it but I don't know that I get with this I will talk to my teacher, thank you everyone

Comment: IMO the correct signature should have been `my_cat_files(string ...$pathes): string`

Comment: Yes should need to be this but I will talk to my teacher for that :)

Comment: I get more of a feeling that they meant `string my_cat_files(string $path, [string $anotherPath [, string $yetAnotherPath]] ...and so on...);`. Not necessarily using a spread operator, but rather just indicating a variable number of parameters.

Comment: The question is gone !  @Cid was right :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're showing is a function that features a [variable-length argument list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list). You have to specify a name after it, as the syntax you're showing is not allowed, even in an interface declaration. Also, the way to specify a return type in PHP is as follows:
`function my_cat_files():string`.

Combining variable-length arguments with the spread operator can be particularly useful:

```
<?php

// Function signature describes _at least_ one argument specifying
// variable-length arguments after $path, which is the only required parameter.
// You're free to pass as many of $additionalPaths
function my_cat_files(string $path, ...$additionalPaths):string
{
    $result = '';
    // Do something with the arguments. 
    // Here's some dummy code.
    
    // Spreading $additionalPaths will evaluate to an empty array if only
    // one argument is passed.
    // Loop over the first argument and any others.
    foreach ([$path, ...$additionalPaths] as $element)
        $result .= (!empty($result)?',':'') . "some_value_for_$element";
        
    return $result;
}

var_dump(my_cat_files('a', 'b', 'c'));
// string(50) "some_value_for_a,some_value_for_b,some_value_for_c"
```

Comment: Please note how the two occurrences of `...$additionalPaths` are not the same thing.

Comment: Hello Really thank you for the contribution for that questions. :)

Comment: @RoAchterberg You might want to add a note: Spread operators inside arrays are available from PHP7.4

Answer (score 0):

I have talk to my teacher, and yeah the exercice is wrong.

The real proto is this:

```php
string my_cat_files(...$path);
```

Comment: Not really. See my answer for the correct way to specify a return type.

Comment: I know your answer, and look the state of the exercices, the teacher confirm me the proto is wrong, so I can continue :) but Thank you so much :)